# How could a GeoJSON look that OGR recognizes more than one layer?

Tags: python, ogr

I load a GeoJSON with OGR and apply the method GetLayerCount().
How must the GeoJSON look like that GetLayerCount() > 1?

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("GeoJSON")
dataset = driver.Open(my.geojson, 0)
# should be 2 or higher
number_of_layers = dataset.GetLayerCount()
```

Unfortunately a FeatureCollection with Features of different Geometry Types does not lead to the desired result.

Comment: Perhaps your real problem is that you have one layer that contains different geometry types (points, lines, polygons) and you can't convert such data into some format that is more limited with this aspect, like shapefiles? That GDAL converts GeoJSON to one layer is documented https://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html `A GeoJSON datasource is translated to single OGRLayer object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way in geojson to have more than one layer. You would need to split the file up into multiple files to achieve this effect.